# Piping into grep using cat returns error: no such file or directory

Tags: bash, grep, pipe, cat

I am practicing on bash. When I try this command, I get an error: "grep: where: No such file or directory".

```
cat file2.txt | tr " " "\n" | grep –i where | wc -l
```

```
Content of file2.txt = 1 2 3 4 where 5 where 7 where
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your command. And it should work as is. Maybe you copy pasted some non visible chars that are messing it. Copy paste the below command and try again by changing for your real values.

```
cat script.sh | tr ' ' '\n' | grep -i echo | wc -l
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: Useless `cat`. Instead provide file input to `tr`: `<script.sh tr ' ' '\n' | grep -i echo | wc -l`. Then instead of `tr` and `wc -l`. Directly asks `grep` to count. `grep -ciwF echo script.sh`

Answer (score 6):

#### Why the error message

If you copy the command from the question and analyze it with a UTF-8 to Unicode interpreter, the `–` before `i` is an en dash U+2013 and not a hyphen-minus `-` (U+002D).  That means `grep` treats the `–i` as the pattern to be searched for and `where` as the file to be searched, which doesn't exist — as the error message says.

```
$ echo "grep –i where | wc -l" | utf8-unicode -w 3
0x67           = U+0067
0x72           = U+0072
0x65           = U+0065
0x70           = U+0070
0x20           = U+0020
0xE2 0x80 0x93 = U+2013
0x69           = U+0069
0x20           = U+0020
0x77           = U+0077
0x68           = U+0068
0x65           = U+0065
0x72           = U+0072
0x65           = U+0065
0x20           = U+0020
0x7C           = U+007C
0x20           = U+0020
0x77           = U+0077
0x63           = U+0063
0x20           = U+0020
0x2D           = U+002D
0x6C           = U+006C
$
```

The code for `utf8-unicode` is now available in my [SOQ](https://github.com/jleffler/soq) (Stack Overflow Questions) repository on GitHub as file `utf8-unicode-1.11.tgz` in the [packages](https://github.com/jleffler/soq/tree/master/packages) sub-directory.  It's the current version — `utf8-unicode -V` reports `utf8-unicode: UTF8-UNICODE Version 1.11 (2017-06-12 06:22:15)` and `utf8-unicode -h` gives help. Using `-w 3` means that it leaves enough space for each code point to be 3 bytes wide, leading to more columnar output (the default is `-w 1`).

#### Other improvements

In the analysis above, I have not addressed how to improve the script more generally.  If you have a sufficiently modern GNU `grep`, you can use just two commands:

```
$ grep -iow where file2.txt | wc -l
```

You can't reduce it to one command; using `grep -ciow where file2.txt` yields 1, not 3 (because there's only one input line that matches).

With a non-GNU `grep`, you might need to use:

```
$ tr ' ' '\n' < file2.txt | grep -ic where
```

[Beware UUoC — Useless Use of `cat`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11710552/15168).

Comment: See the update to the question for where to get the source for `utf8-unicode`.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple ways:

With GNU `grep`:

```sh
grep -oiw echo script.sh | wc -l
```

- `-o`: Output matches only.
- `-i`: Case-insensitive matches.
- `-w`: Whole word matches.
- `wc -l`: Counting matches.

With `sed` to split commands into one per line:

```sh
sed 's/[[:space:][:punct:]]\+/\n/g' script.sh | grep -ciF echo
```

- `sed 's/[[:space:][:punct:]]\+/\n/g'`: Replace all spaces, carriage returns, tabs, punctuation with a newline.
- `grep -ciF echo`: Count lines with case-insensitive match of plain text `echo` (no RegEx).